# ffmpeg-python outputs black screen when trying to save as mp4

Tags: python, ffmpeg

This is my code. I am trying to make a video out of all pictures in the `pics2` directory using ffmpeg.

```
import subprocess

command = 'ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i "pics2/Image%02d.png" -r 1 -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p Output.mp4'
p = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

This saves an Output.mp4 successfully but the video has no frames (It is completely black)

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hello! Can you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve with this script? It seems that you are trying to create a `.mp4` from a set of images joined together. If you give us a bit more context, I can surely help you better.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou. I have updated the question. Hope it is clear. Please ask me if you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your player does not like 1 fps

Many players behave similarly.

You can still provide a low frame rate for the input, but give a more normal frame rate for the output. `ffmpeg` will simply duplicate the frames. The output video won't look different than your original command, but it will play.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i "pics2/Image%02d.png" -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p Output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original script occurs when setting both `-framerate` and `-r`. [Here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/13074) is more information about it. Try using this as your command:

`command = "ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i 'pics2/Image%02d.png' -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p Output.mp4"`

Brief explanation (based on Saaru Lindestøkke's answer):

```
ffmpeg               <- call ffmpeg
    -framerate 1     <- set the input framerate to 1
    -i 'pics2/Image%02d.png' <- read PNG images with filename Image01, Image02, etc...
    -vcodec libx264  <- Set the codec to libx264
    -s 1280x720      <- Set the resolution to 1280x720
    -pix_fmt yuv420p <- Set the pixel format to planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp
    Output.mp4       <- the output filename
```

Answer (score 0):

can scale the video using -vf scale=500:-2 this fixed black video issue for me