# FFMPEG exported video is all black

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to generate a video wall of 4 videos using ffmpeg like the given image

[image]

I am exceuting this below script to get the desired result

```
def merge_videos(output_file):
    command = [
        'path_to_ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe',
        '-i', 'path/playblasts/front.mp4',
        '-i', 'path/playblasts/side.mp4',
        '-i', 'path/playblasts/persp1.mp4',
        '-i', 'path/playblasts/persp2.mp4',
        '-filter_complex', '[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0[v]',
        '-map', '[v]',
        output_file
    ]
    subprocess.run(command)
```

where as passing output file path as argument, but I am getting below result

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the desired result using the exact script you've provided (ffmpeg 6.1.1), so **the Python script and given ffmpeg args work fine**. The problem may be with the input videos and/or your setup, so you'll have to dig more into this on your machine. Here are some suggestions that might help:

- In general, when debugging problems with many components involved (like Python, ffmpeg, encoders, decoders, your video player, etc.), it helps to **isolate the problem as much as possible**. You're running ffmpeg via Python here. If the problem persists when you run ffmpeg directly in the command line, then it's not a Python-related problem. Less headache already :) If it persists with any input video, then it's not input-related, etc.
- Check your ffmpeg version first, update if needed. It may be a bug that has been fixed a while ago.
- It may be a player compatibility issue. Try forcing the output framerate by adding `-r 10` (before the output, not the inputs - order is important for ffmpeg) as some players can't handle too-low fps. Try `-pix_fmt yuv420p` and [scaling the video down](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling#KeepingtheAspectRatio) with `-vf scale=1920:-2` (the output resolution might've been too high). [This's helped other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080205/ffmpeg-python-outputs-black-screen-when-trying-to-save-as-mp4).
- Pay attention to warnings/errors in the ffmpeg output, try searching them.
- Try other encoders like libx265, libvpx-vp9, etc. If this helps, but encoding is too slow and you prefer encoding speed over perceptual quality per bit/s, check if there're any hardware encoders available to you like hevc_nvenc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input, i figured out the issue, it was because of different encoding from a 3D DCC, once i changed it worked fine.

Comment: By any chance, can you help me with one more thing though, I want to add black orders to seprate all 4 of the videos, how can I do it ?

Comment: @Kartikey glad! For borders use the pad filter, example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/8682376).

Comment: PS. for solely ffmpeg-related questions in the future, I suppose, https://video.stackexchange.com will be a better fit :)

Comment: Thanks fir your response and reference , it was helpful :)